# Struggling with Ember-data's REST adapter and nested resources

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm really struggling with Ember-data's REST adapter and nested resources and would appreciate any help... I'm using the latest (1.0.4pre) version of Ember and Ember-data (revision: 11).

I have 2 simple models:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name:     DS.attr('string'),
  email:    DS.attr('string'),
  schemes:  DS.hasMany('App.Scheme')
});

App.Scheme = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  users: DS.hasMany('App.User')
});
```

and simple nested routes:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("user", { path: "users/:user_id" }, function() {
    this.resource("schemes");
  });
});
```

I have a Rails 3 JSON API which has the following endpoints:

```
/users/:user_id
/users/:user_id/schemes
```

When I navigate to `users/:user_id/schemes` in my ember app I want to retrieve all user's schemes, however by default Ember-data requests `/schemes`, which isn't an endpoint in my API - I can add it but I need to scope schemes by user, I do not have the concept of current_user as I want to view any user and her schemes.

Is there a way of either forcing Ember to look at `/users/:user_id/schemes` or to append a query parameter to Ember's default ajax call, eg: `/schemes?user_id=:user_id`?

Alternatively, is there a way of adding to the ajax request headers, which in turn my rails API can read and set up the `/schemes` response accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this feature has been discussed quite a bit, but not yet implemented. [This issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/186) contains sample code for a quick work-around.

You could also use:

```
var userSchemes = App.Scheme.find({ used_id: 'id' });
```

to query `/schemes?user_id=id`.

Comment: Thanks @ahmacleod.

Using `App.Scheme.find({ user_id: 'id' });` works for now, but is seems like a cheap workaround. I guess that's what comes of riding with young technology!